# 2 arrays, need the result to be what i show

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is my arrays, i want this result below, but cant figure it out.

The result is a count of how many times an ID have a date between 2014-06-01 to the last day of month 2014-06-xx

In my array with dates "array[1]", only 6-7-8 have wrong dates.

Help please :-S

**RESULT**

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2
        [4] => 2
        [7] => 3
        [9] => 1
        [12] => 1
        [13] => 1
    )
)


Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 7
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 7
        [6] => 3
        [7] => 3
        [8] => 4
        [9] => 9
        [10] => 12
        [11] => 2
        [12] => 13
        [13] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2014-06-18
        [1] => 2014-06-10
        [2] => 2014-06-05
        [3] => 2014-06-05
        [4] => 2014-06-12
        [5] => 2014-06-11
        [6] => 2013-12-12
        [7] => 2014-07-23
        [8] => 2014-05-13
        [9] => 2014-06-01
        [10] => 2014-06-12
        [11] => 2014-06-04
        [12] => 2014-06-04
        [13] => 2014-06-11
    )

)
```

Comment: What are we looking at? What are those numbers?

Comment: To get a top 3 of last month

Comment: Is the first array in your "RESULT" the result array you would like to have? If so, why is the count for id 4 = 1; it should be 2, right?

Comment: Orders, only date and id is displayed

Comment: Thats right, with the id 4, i changed it now to 2, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following works. Did not test it.

```
$idsArray = $yourArray[0];
$dateArray = $yourArray[1];
$countArray = array(); // the result array

$beginningTimestamp = strtotime('2014-06-01');
$lastTimestamp = strtotime('2014-07-01');  // before the first of July comes the last of June

foreach ($idsArray as $key => $id) {
   if (isset($dateArray[$key])) {
     $timestamp = strtotime($dateArray[$key];
     if ($timestamp >= $beginningTimestamp && $timestamp < $lastTimestamp) {
        if (isset($countArray[$id])) {
           $countArray[$id]++;
        } else {
           $countArray[$id] = 1;
        }
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Wee, thank you alot, it works like i want it to. Im not very familiar with dates. But thanks :-)